# Django Processing Form to other Form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a view that is an input form that people input their information in (name, address, that sort of thing). They will then click an "ok" button.

After people click "ok" I want them to be redirected to a page that has a table with their inputted information.

Any ideas on how to do this?

So far, I have the first view. When clicking OK all the information is stored in a database. I just don't know how to use it from there.

Note: ModelForms are used

Comment: All the basic tutorials I've seen about django show this exact procedure defined.  I would suggest https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/generic-views/

Comment: We need more information. Firstly, are you using a Form or ModelForm?

Comment: @Francis, I'm using ModelForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look carefully the documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#processing-the-data-from-a-form

You could understand that, once you have treated (`is_valid() - cleaned_data['']`), you have to do a call to 
`render_to_response('template',{ 'name':name, 'last_name':last_name..}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

And, in the template called, just make the data you need be shown, as usual..

Comment: but the template for this view is the actual input form. I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean..

Comment: Ok,so i'm not sure to understand what you want too! :D

Answer (score 0):

you could try to pass your newly created object to the next view (which shows the new object) like this, the called view just has to accept your object as parameter.

```
# ... your form processing here
if form.is_valid():
    # create and save your object code here
    your_object.save()
    return redirect('show_new_data_view', your_object=your_object)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Consider my code as example only, the NoReverseMatch maybe raises because you dont have your url patterns setup to match your needs, maybe you could share a bit of your code (like the views and urls).